# Error trying to create map outside of main function. C++

Tags: c++, maps

I'm very new to C++ but I am trying to create a map and insert values into it from a class but seem to keep getting an error.

```cpp
class Album {
public:
    map<string,string> albums;
    albums.insert(make_pair("rap","Kamikaze")); // This gives the error
};
```

when i put those same two lines inside the main function, it works without an issue. Like I said I'm very new to C++ so please don't roast me if it's something simple.
(Also, I have map included and using namespace std added)

Comment: C++ does not work this way.  Executable lines of code belong in functions.  What is your intent of having that `insert` call there?  When exactly will that line of code be invoked?

Comment: A C++ class can contain member variables or member functions (some of these are special, such as the constructor, destructor, etc.). All member functions and variables can be public, private, or protected. Your class has a line of code that is not part of a function which is not allowed. If you want this code to be executed every time you create a new instance of the class, maybe it could go in the constructor (probably not what you want). You probably want an insert member function, that you will then call on an instance of your class once you have created one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to run code in a space where code isn't supposed to be. You can instead write

```cpp
class Album {
public:
    map<string,string> albums;

    Album() {
        albums.insert(make_pair("rap","Kamikaze"));
    }
};
```

This will run the code every time the class is instantiated, effectively making it the default value for `albums`.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Class is not a function. Class body can only contain declarations. Executable code may only be in functions (including class methods). For example:

```
class Album {
public:
    map<string,string> albums;
    void add_album(string a, string b) {
        albums.insert(make_pair(a, b));
        // or: albums.emplace(a, b); // if supported
    }
};
...
int main() {
...
    Album my_album;
    my_album.add_album("rap", "Kamikaze");
    my_album.albums.insert(make_pair("some", "Thing"));
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No problem its very simple. Below here is a class definition and map that you have declared is its public data member.
Now this Class will act as a prototype for all "Album" objects and all object created will have their own map member.

```
class Album {
public:
    map<string,string> albums;

};
```

Consider below example,

```
    Album objA; //Object of Album class is created here

   //Map being a public member can directly be accessed here
    ObjA.albums.insert(make_pair("some", "Thing"));
```

So instead of calling insert function in class definition you need to do it this way.

Similarly for objectB,

```
 ObjB.albums.insert(make_pair("some", "Thing"));
```